# String value converted to double automatically change to decimal value in Swift

Tags: swift, string, double

Working with Swift.
I am converting value from String to double.

```
let value: String = "8"    
var size: Double   
size = Double(value) 
size = 8.0 // 8.0
```

Result should be 8 unless string value is 8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Double` only stores a numeric magnitude. `"8"` and `"8.0"` have the same magnitude, so they get represented by the same `Double` value. Whether you show trailing `0`s or not is a consequence of how you choose to format and present your values.

`print` does it one way for debugging, but `NumberFormatter` gives you more control to format numbers for real, non-debugging purposes.

Comment: So i can use NumberFormatter to format the Double Value?

Comment: @iosdeveloper Yep.

Comment: @iosdeveloper yes just make sure to use `Formatter`'s method `string(for: Any)` instead of `string(from: NSNumber)` when